# Move Array element using PHP/Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5

I am trying to move 2 elements in my array. When I output the current array, this is my result:

```
 array:["Date" => "2016-09-25"
      "emp" => "12345  "
      "work" => "coding"
      "Hours" => "6.00"
      "L" => "L"
      "IBEW" => "IBEW"
      ]
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to move the two values (`L` and `IBEW`) to the second and third place, like this:

```
array:["Date" => "2016-09-25"
      "emp" => "12345"
      "L" => "L"
      "IBEW" => "IBEW"
      "work" => "coding"
      "Hours" => "6.00"
       ]
```

How is this possible?

Comment: you have to change the fields in table of database

Comment: why you need it so ??

Comment: for your expected output because arrays comes according to fields saved in table of database

Comment: "L" => "L"
"IBEW" => "IBEW"  these two columns are not in database this vitrual columns we are pushing in array

Comment: are you using hidden fields, are you using dynamic or static

Comment: are you ok with below answer

Comment: @naveenkumar i am fetching from database dynamically in array these two columns i am pushing in last of the array   
"L" => "L" "IBEW" => "IBEW"

Comment: @naveenkumar No I am fetching dynamically but here he is saying swap the position I do not have static array

Comment: @Murali I used a static array just to ilustrate the example with the same array that you put as "Current Output" in the question, but of course, you can swap a dynamic array with the same code (if the field names are right).

Comment: @nanocv tell him the way then how to swap while print_r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have a working and tested answer for that.

You just have to change `$output` to the right variable name.

```
foreach ($output as &$outputItem) {

  // Here we store the elements to move in an auxiliar array
  $arrayOfElementsToMove = [
      "L" => $outputItem["L"],
      "IBEW" => $outputItem["IBEW"]
  ];

  // We remove the elements of the original array
  unset($outputItem["L"]);
  unset($outputItem["IBEW"]);

  // We store the numeric position of CostCode key
  $insertionPosition = array_search("CostCode", array_keys($outputItem));

  // We increment in 1 the insertion position (to insert after CostCode)
  $insertionPosition++;

  // We build the new array with 3 parts: items before CostCode, "L and IBEW" array, and items after CostCode
  $outputItem = array_slice($outputItem, 0, $insertionPosition, true) +
          $arrayOfElementsToMove +
          array_slice($outputItem, $insertionPosition, NULL, true);
}
```

Comment: @Murali Then it would be great if you edit your question to add the code of the database connection, just for us to check the method you are using and the field names.

Comment: i was attached my screen shot image. without the parent array your answer is correct but hear parent array is coming that is the pblm for me

Comment: @Murali Edited my answer. Hope it helps!

Comment: only one record your answer is woking fine.. but i have more records in your answer is taking last record

Comment: @Murali In the picture showed before you edited the question there was a main array with two associative arrays inside. That main array is my `$output` variable. The `foreach` loop goes through all the arrays inside and swap the keys to the order you wanted.

Comment: Thanks is working fine. I was doing wrong. Your answer is correct!.. thanks alot @nanocv

Answer (score 0):

```
For Example Have append the 'L' AND 'IDEW' key values after the work key,

<?php

# For Example Have append the 'L' AND 'IDEW' key values after the work key
$main_array = [
"Date" => "2016-09-25",
"emp" => "12345  ",
"work" => "coding",
"Hours" => "6.00",
"L" => "L",
"IBEW" => "IBEW"
];

$split_values = array("L"=>$main_array["L"], "IBEW"=>$main_array["IBEW"]);

unset($main_array['L']);
unset($main_array['IBEW']);

$array_decide = 0;

foreach($main_array as $k=>$v){
    if ($array_decide == 0){
        $array_first[$k] = $v;
    } elseif ($array_decide == 1) {
        $array_final[$k] = $v;
    }
    if ($k=='work'){
        $array_final = array_merge($array_first,$split_values);
        $array_decide = 1;
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($array_final);
echo "</pre>";

/*OUTPUT:
Array
(
    [Date] => 2016-09-25
    [emp] => 12345  
    [work] => coding
    [L] => L
    [IBEW] => IBEW
    [Hours] => 6.00
)*/


?>
```